# How would you interpret and make a full sentence of 漂{ただよ}う 僕{ぼく}達{たち} in English?

Tags: translation

I was wondering how you would translate this into an English sentence? I know that 漂う means "to drift" and 僕達 means "us", but I'm confused as to how to make a complete English sentence out of this.

Here's the full stanza (because this is from a song):

- 少しだけ寂しいけど　笑って  (I will feel a little lonely, but let's smile)
- 「さよなら」の代わりに言おう (and instead of saying "goodbye")
- ｢またね・また会いましょう」 (let's say "see you / let's meet again")
- アオイハル　漂う　僕達     (???)

https://youtu.be/WEF3g7TPz-U?t=1m41s

(アオイハル is the title of the song, I know it means "Green Spring", does it actually add any meaning to the sentence?)

Thanks!

Comment: アオイハル (青い春) means *green spring*, not *blue summer*.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for that. Must be still half-asleep from my nap..
Doesn't 青い mean blue though?

Comment: You'll find this green/blue dichotomy a lot because they were once considered different shades of the same colour (notice how we call orange hair 'red', even though we now consider orange a separate colour).

Comment: @Nothingatall I love your English example for comparison! Just wanted to add for the op that, more specifically, 青 is still used to mean "green" for traffic lights (青になった = "turned green") and plants (including vegetables/fruits like 青りんご). There may be other cases, but that's all I've found so far.

Comment: 「アオイハル・[青]{あお}い[春]{はる}」って、「[青春]{せいしゅん}」のことですよね・・・?  -> http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E9%9D%92%E6%98%A5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Those of us drifting in the green spring [*青春{アオイハル}* (*seishun*)]

If *aoiharu* is an artistic-reference to [*seishun*](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9D%92%E6%98%A5) then this translation could work? I feel the lyricist is trying to tap into the fact that those in *seishun* are young and somewhat green or lost (read: drifting) but that's just a guess.